# java mulithreading deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading

I was asked to created a dead lock situation. Below code is never creating me dead lock although there is a chance of getting dead lock. 
The reason is as follows.
If method1() and method2() both will be called by two or many threads , there is a good chance of deadlock because if thead 1 aquires lock on Sting object while executing method1() and thread 2 acquires lock on Integer object while executing method2() both will be waiting for each other to release lock on Integer and String to proceed further which will never happen.

I wanted to create a dead lock situation but is not creating it.

```
class Task implements Runnable {

        public void method1() {
            synchronized (String.class) {
                System.out.println("Aquired lock on String.class object");

                synchronized (Integer.class) {
                    System.out.println("Aquired lock on Integer.class object");
                }
            }
        }

        public void method2() {
            synchronized (Integer.class) {
                System.out.println("Aquired lock on Integer.class object");

                synchronized (String.class) {
                    System.out.println("Aquired lock on String.class object");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            method1();
            method2();

        }
    }

    public class DeadLock {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Runnable r= new Task();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(r);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(r);
            t1.start();
            t2.start();

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: update my the post. I wanted to create dead lock scenario

Comment: u r job is always down voting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to increase the chance for deadlock, you can sleep the thread after it acquires the first lock, and before it tries to acquires the second lock. One rough example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      synchronized (String.class) {
        System.out.println("Thread 1 after acquiring String lock");
        Thread.sleep(5000); // Sleep for 5 seconds
        synchronized (Integer.class) {
          System.out.println("Thread 1 after acquiring Integer lock");
        }
      }
    }
  });

  Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      synchronized (Integer.class) {
        System.out.println("Thread 2 after acquiring Integer lock");
        Thread.sleep(5000); // Sleep for 5 seconds
        synchronized (String.class) {
          System.out.println("Thread 2 after acquiring String lock");
        }
      }
    }
  });

  t1.start();
  t2.start();
}
```

You will see:

```
Thread 1 after acquiring String lock
Thread 2 after acquiring Integer lock
```

or

```
Thread 2 after acquiring Integer lock
Thread 1 after acquiring String lock
```

and then deadlock happens.

Comment: thanks @fajarkoe. It seems there was dead lock. It is not throwing any exception. How do I print dead lock exception details?

Comment: Deadlock has no exception. Exception is generated when the code throws an exception. Perhaps you can elaborate more what kind of details that you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely create a deadlock, as the Task always attempts method1 then method2. You need to have 2 different runnables which call method1 and method2 in opposing orders. Additionally, you probably should consider using a countdown latch that your tasks must wait for at the beginning of `run()` to provide a higher probability of the 2 threads actually executing concurrently.

Comment: Ok thanks , but why do we need to create two Runnables? and where should I move the two methods. do you mean create another Runnable and call methods in revers order?